# Paginação na categoria do Wordpress retornando 404

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Olá!

Eu sei que provavelmente essa é uma pergunta repetida, mas como nenhuma das soluções que eu achei por aqui conseguiram resolver o meu problema, eu decidi fazê-la assim mesmo.

Eu estou trabalhando num template com um custom post type. Para fazer a paginação, usei esse tutorial aqui https://medium.com/@bikramkc/wordpress-custom-pagination-functions-php-without-a-plugin-961bc4fb930f

Ele funciona perfeitamente no archive do meu cpt, mas nas categorias do mesmo, quando mudo de página ele me retorna um 404.

Segue o código:

```
// archive.php

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = [
    "post_type" => "clientes",
    "posts_per_page" => '12',
    "paged" => $paged
];
query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) :
    ?>
<ul class="customers-section--list">
    <?php
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
[...]
<?php
    if (function_exists('custom_pagination')) {
        custom_pagination($loop->max_num_pages, "", $paged);
    }
endif;
?>
```

```
// category.php

<?php

    $currCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
    $cat_name = $currCat->name;
    $cat_id   = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = [
        "post_type" => "clientes",
        "posts_per_page" => '12',
        "paged" => $paged,
        'category_name' => $cat_name
    ];
    query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) :
?>
<ul class="customers-section--list">
    <?php
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
[...]
<?php
    if (function_exists('custom_pagination')) {
        custom_pagination($loop->max_num_pages, "", $paged);
    }
endif;
```

Custom post type setup

```
add_action('init', 'cpt_customers');
function cpt_customers()
{
    $labels = [
        'name' => 'Clientes',
        'singular_name' => 'Cliente'
    ];

    $args = [
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'],
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-groups',
        'taxonomies' => ['category'],
        'has_archive' => true,
    ];

    register_post_type('clientes', $args);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paginação não vai funcionar corretamente, pois você esta utilizando a função `query_posts()` que deve ser utilizada apenas internamente no WordPress, documentação deles deixa claro que não deve ser utilizada dentro de temas ou plugins, já que essa função vai reescrever o loop da página, causando problemas conhecidos de performance e paginação.

Veja a documentação, tem todos os detalhes e explicando os motivos de não usar com mais detalhes e também alternativas para implementação: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

Mas enfim, no seu caso o correto é usar `pre_get_posts`, assim você pode modificar o loop sem forçar ele rodar novamente enquanto esta carregando a página.

Além que registrando o post type que você quer, já são criadas pastas para arquivos e categorias, sem precisar modificar nenhum arquivo, entretanto se você precisa mudar o nome, como eu falei, use `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: Consegui! Também precisei fazer algumas alterações no menu permalink, mas funcionou aqui. Muito obrigado! :D